# How to display image when click the select option using jquery, css

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

How to show an image while we select the option below.

Example : -

```
<select name="payment">
<option value="">Please Select</option>
<option value="Paypal">Paypal</option>
<option value="Bank">Bank</option>
</select>

<div id="payment"><img src="paypal.gif" alt="paypal" /></div>
```

If we select paypal on div `id="payment"` will show the logo paypal and if bank will show bank logo.

Can be done with jquery? let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Doh, misread the question, updated:*
You can do this with just a small event handler, like this:

```
$(function() {
  $("select[name=payment]").bind("change", function() {
    $("#payment img").attr('src', $(this).val().toLowerCase() + ".gif");
  }).change();
});
```

This approach adjusts the `src` of the image based on the current selected value.  Also, we're triggering the event one time on `document.ready` to make the initial hide/show state match the dropdown.

Comment: @James - Was just editing to change that, re-read the question for an ID and realized that wasn't what he wanted.

Comment: thanks working!. I added please select. How to disable the image if value is empty

Comment: Er Bob. You need to start thinking for yourself here mate.

Answer (score 2):

Assumption: your bank logo is called bank.gif.

EDIT: added code to check for blank value.

```
$('select[name=payment]').change(function() {

  var val = $(this).val();

  $('div#payment img')
    .attr('src', val + '.gif')
    .css('display', val.length ? 'block' : 'none');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to hide the paypal.gif first

```
<select name="payment">
<option value="Paypal">Paypal</option>
<option value="Bank">Bank</option>
</select>

<div id="payment"><img src="paypal.gif' alt="paypal' /></div>
```

Then bind a change handler to the select.

```
<script>
var images = { 
    'Paypal': 'paypal.gif', 
    'Bank': 'bankLogo.gif'
};

$("select").bind("change",function(){
    $("div#payment img:first").attr('src', images[$("select :selected").val()] );
});
</script>
```

Comment: This is what I thought at first too, but he edited the question, he wants to show the `bank.gif` if it's bank, `paypal.gif` if it's paypal.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! Updated.

Comment: Ah the old edit the question trick. I wondered why both of you had missed that :D